# Change the number display in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I need to display in a list view some data about numbers. I get these data from a database that is sqlite.

Im using a simplecursoradapter to fill the listview. The problem is that numbers >= to one million are stored in exponential format. So for example if I insert a number like 1000 000 then it gets stored as 1+06E. The problem is that i need to display it as 1 000 000. But I can't manage to change that format inside the cursor or the simplecursoradapter.

My code for filling the listview is:

```
Cursor c = admin.obtenerCursorGastosVarFecha(fechaSelUs);

      // The desired columns to be bound
      String[] columnas = new String[] {"_id", "Descripcion", "Costo", "Fecha_Creado"};

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] views = new int[] {R.id.IdGstVar, R.id.DescGstVar, R.id.CostoGstVar, R.id.FechaGstVar };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lista_gastos_variables, c, columnas, views, 0);
```

Im getting here all as a string, but numbers higher or equal to one million show up in exponential numbers

I tried this code, but its not working at all.

It just modifies values lower than ten million and also, it rounds or changes the values, so if insert for example 8 888 888 it displays 8 888 890.

I need to display in natural numbers all the numbers stored in the database.

Also if there is a way to insert rows with numbers into the database without them being changed to exponential format, how is it done?  Thank you very much for your help!

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {

                if( column == 2 ){ // let's suppose that the column 0 is the date
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;

                    // here you use SimpleDateFormat to bla blah blah
                    tv.setText(""+Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Costo"))));
                    return true;
                }




                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't parse it in Double. You can display is as String. in that case it won't show up in exponential format.

Comment: Hi, i edited the question. There it shows how i fill the list view. I Just let the textviews display the values as strings. But still show up as exponential fomat. I dont know what to do o solve this. I was thinking that maybe i can save Reals in the sqlite in a way that it doesnt turn into exponential numbers, but still dont know how to do it. I guess im gonna try until i get it

Comment: what is the datatype of costo in db  ??

Comment: what a shame!!!  D:   The datatype i used was a REAL. And I created again the tables using text, and it works!  Im sorry for wasting your time. Still not used to sqlite type things

Comment: Since i Cant answer my own questio, Ill post it here:

Brijesh Thakur gave me the idea of storing numbers as Text insteed of Real in the Sqlite database. This was able to solve the problems in which large numbers with 6 or more digits were stored as exponential numbers. If use Text i can store 10 000 000 and will retrieve it as 10 000 000. Using reals the number is retrived as 10+6E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using datatype as real , and storing it into db as real number. At the time of storing into SqliteDB,  it converts it into exponential format. When you are trying to read it from database it gives you the converted exponential format into string. You just change the datatype to `varchar` for costo. It will solve your problem.